# Convert file .pptx to image using Java

Tags: java, image, pdf, powerpoint

Is there a way to convert pptx to an image? My aim is to finally generate an PDF file.
I try with Aspose but there are some issue. With Apache POI, it don't support PPTX. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `PPTX SVGExporter` in [DocX4j](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j/browser/trunk/docx4j/src/pptx4j/java/org/pptx4j/convert/out/svginhtml/SvgExporter.java?rev=1086) that may help you, in conjonction with Batik (from SVVG to PDF)

Note : I've not tested it

Comment: I tested it already, i is some bugs with. I don't have the background, the style is not very good etc.

Comment: Yes, SVG export in pptx4j is a work in progress.  Support is currently limited to text boxes and images; arbitrary VML & DrawingML is not converted to SVG. 

But it is open source, and if you don't need all those other shapes, scratching your itch might be within your grasp.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to write a small native library that Java calls to do the operation.  I'm pretty sure you can use a .NET language or C++ to connect to powerpoint and have it "print" to either PDF or some other usable format.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690936%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is a small sample application which does some automation.

Comment: I find the following code : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2008/09/24/convert-office-documents-docx-pptx-pub-into-pdf-programmatically.aspx

How can I use it in Java? or maybe I can re-write it, but I don't know how to convert a reference.